# Unable to remove model property in Sequelize query

Tags: sequelize.js

Using sequelize we are unable to perform a query which includes a field from other model (Player) without including the name of the model as property.

We would like to obtain this result (look to the last property of each object: number):

```
[ { id: '35',
   username: '4f224bd78d1a943ead9db2f73991e93dc8227335',
   firstName: '8c81f070b9adad3d3693',
   lastName: 'f9f5792d8a827e83974b',
   email: 'd6fd38bb112da3a55b23@3c1f780dea427bc097ab.com',
   created_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.676Z',
   updated_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.676Z',
   deleted_at: null,
   number: null },

 { id: '36',
   username: '613400c032540519fce322f4aa6abdb082834005',
   firstName: '8bbc5692042ea4ce06f6',
   lastName: 'b26d6701c275e07e1ea1',
   email: '59e8d5b35185810a31e5@41677c1723806c2afac0.com',
   created_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.768Z',
   updated_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.768Z',
   deleted_at: null,
   number: 10 } ]
```

Instead we get this:

```
[ { id: '35',
   username: '4f224bd78d1a943ead9db2f73991e93dc8227335',
   firstName: '8c81f070b9adad3d3693',
   lastName: 'f9f5792d8a827e83974b',
   email: 'd6fd38bb112da3a55b23@3c1f780dea427bc097ab.com',
   created_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.676Z',
   updated_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.676Z',
   deleted_at: null,
   Player: { number: null } },
 { id: '36',
   username: '613400c032540519fce322f4aa6abdb082834005',
   firstName: '8bbc5692042ea4ce06f6',
   lastName: 'b26d6701c275e07e1ea1',
   email: '59e8d5b35185810a31e5@41677c1723806c2afac0.com',
   created_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.768Z',
   updated_at: '2017-03-16T07:35:15.768Z',
   deleted_at: null,
   Player: { number: 10 } } ]
```

We have 4 models involved: User (have almost all the properties), Player (have number), Role (contains the roles) and UserRole (relates users and roles).

```
async function getPlayers() {
   const playerRole = await sequelize.models.Role.getPlayerRole();    

   return sequelize.models.User.findAll({
     include: [{
       association: sequelize.models.User.hasOne(sequelize.models.UserRole),
       model: sequelize.models.UserRole,
       where: {
         club_id: this.clubId,
         team_id: this.id,
         role_id: playerRole.id
       }
     }, {
       association: sequelize.models.User.hasOne(sequelize.models.Player),
       model: sequelize.models.Player,
       where: {
         team_id: this.id,
       },
       attributes: ['number']
     }]
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`sequelize.col()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol), but you should probably add `raw: true` to the `findAll` call because otherwise the result will be translated to `User` model instances, so the `number` attribute would be ignored anyway.

```js
return sequelize.models.User.findAll({
    attributes: { include: sequelize.col('Player.number') },
    raw: true, // added to prevent returning User instances from the query, only simple JSON data
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.models.UserRole,
            where: {
                club_id: this.clubId,
                team_id: this.id,
               role_id: playerRole.id
            }
        },
        {
            model: sequelize.models.Player,
            where: {
                team_id: this.id,
            },
            attributes: []
        }
    ]
});
```

I have removed the `association` attributes - I assume that you have declared them in model definitions so there is no need to at them every time while doing query.

The `col()` method must be called on Sequelize instance.

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your fast and complete response.